# How to delete the extra spacing in code after it is printed?

Tags: c++

I have been working on a project. I am limited to using a few libraries so any additional library would not be helpful. I am noticing an extra space after the last number when the calendar is finished. How do I fix this extra spacing issue? please help! Here's an example picture of the output.
**UPDATE: Thanks Drew for helping me with the alignment!

```
//extracted code..
#include <iostream>

int main() {
         int day = 0;
         if (day > 9)
         {
            std::cout << day << '\n';
         }
         else
         {
            std::cout << day << '\n' << " ";
         }
}
```

Comment: Find out which blank comes from which output, e.g. by replacing them by ".", "_", "#" etc.

Comment: Is your last `else` statement with no `{`brackets`}` a bug, or just deceptive indentation?

Comment: I have and that is why I said I know it's after the number becomes double digits. I just do not know how to fix it...

Comment: For single-digit days: if you want them to align left, then don't print a space at the beginning of the row (as you do in `std::cout << day << '\n' << " "`). If you want them to align right, then print a space before the digit, not after (as you do in `std::cout << day << " ";`)

Comment: Change one of your `if (day > 9)` statements to `if (day >= 9)`.

Comment: For some reason, when I add brackets to it, the whole program messes up.. as in the numbers after '9' loose spacing. I think it is deceptive indentation, haha but that has been giving me issues too.

Comment: When you are tinkering with code like this, instead of writing things like `cout << " ";... cout << " ";`, try writing `cout << "A";... cout << "B";`. That way you can see exactly which line of code is printing which character. Once everything works, you can switch back to spaces.

Comment: The accepted solution tinkers by applying a two-digit solution to a one digit number, "9". This is introducing an uncleanliness to compensate for the other one, which is that you introduce a four blanks start, in spite of obviously trying for a column width of three. I recommend to clean up, instead of increasing the problems. You were quick with accepting. So I assume that you will not appreciate a clean solution.

Comment: @Yunnosch is not wrong.  My answer makes your attempt work, but there are easily more reliable attempts that could be made.

Comment: @DrewDormann Which attempt of mine are you referring to?

Comment: You can choose one of the previous answers, since they solve your problem or, for the future, try to use ANSII escape sequences, to move the cursor on the terminal and go back of a backspace with a command (this is useful in the case in which you need to delete more than one space, for example). You can look at this one: https://github.com/JustWhit3/osmanip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change every `(day > 9)` to `(day >= 9 )`.

You are using that condition to decide how much whitespace should appear *after* the number.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fqc6dxMnM)